# Is my Django ModelForm unbound?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

For the past days, I have been battling with a `CreateView` and a corresponding `ModelForm`: I can't get the form to process the POSTed data and save the object. When submitting the data, I get sent back to the same page with the form.

`{{ form.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` don't output anything in my template, so there do not seem to be any errors.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to manually bind the data to the form?

**views.py**

```
class CreateFlyerView(CreateView, CookLoginRequired):
    template_name = 'flyer/create.html'
    model = Flyer
    form_class = CreateFlyerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('flyer_start')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateFlyerView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(CreateFlyerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         now = datetime.datetime.now()
         meals_as_host = MenuOffer.objects.filter(deleted=False, host=self.request.user).order_by('cdate')
         upcoming_meals_as_host = meals_as_host.filter(eating_time__gte=now).order_by('cdate')[:4]
         past_flyers = Flyer.objects.filter(host=self.request.user, cdate__lt=now)

         context.update({
             'upcoming_meals_as_host': upcoming_meals_as_host,
             'past_flyers': past_flyers,
             'user_images': Image.objects.filter(account=self.request.user),
                 })
         return context
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateFlyerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    picture = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Image.objects.all())
    meals = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=MenuOffer.objects.all())
    headline = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Flyer
        fields = ['headline', 'copy', 'avatar', 'style', 'greeting', 'picture', 'meals']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CreateFlyerForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['headline'].initial = _(u'Some headline with {}').format(user.neighborhood if user.neighborhood else user.place)
        self.fields['copy'].initial = _(u'Some copy.')
        self.fields['avatar'].initial = user.image
        self.fields['style'].initial = 'MODERN'
        self.fields['greeting'].initial = user.first_name
        self.fields['picture'].queryset = Image.objects.filter(account=user)
        self.fields['meals'].queryset = MenuOffer.objects.filter(deleted=False, host=user, eating_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now()).order_by('cdate')[:4]
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't kicking you out because the session has expired? What does `CookLoginRequired` do? If it is for limiting access to a particular user, make sure you are inheriting from [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Making sure that I am inheriting from UserPassesTestMixin is a good suggestion. Although that wasn't the problem. Alasdair's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the `super()` call in the `__init__` method. Therefore the form is always initialised with `data=None` so it's an unbound form.

It should be:

```
class CreateFlyerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CreateFlyerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
```